# Update table by selecting column values from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-synapse

Could you please help on the below request.

**Table1**(this is our control/metadata table where we store some column names of the tables for our operations)

| tableID | columnnames |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | cust_email_ID |
| 1 | cust_name |

**Table2**(actual table)

| cust_email_ID | cust_name |
| --- | --- |
| First | row |
| Second | row |

All I want is to update table2 by passing the values from table1(control table) as column names

example:

```sql
update table2 set get_column_names_from_table1 ='somevalue' where table2column=somevalue
```

Comment: Honestly, fix your design. This is not a path you want to go down. You will need dynamic SQL everywhere. This is, with respect, just a bad idea. Look into a normalised approach.

Comment: _some column names of the tables_ There is too much implied here. Post DDL and sample data for your tables along with the desired results. You write "tables" (plural) but there is no obvious way to know how to associate rows among the various tables (surely more than two) in your database. And perhaps explain how the query writer (you or your app) knows that 'somevalue' should be set for cust_email_ID and not cust_name. This does seem to be a terribly complicated and risky design.